# Using gcloud compute copy-files with custom port

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

Is there any way to set custom port number in **gcloud compute copy-files**?
The [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/copy-files) says nothing about it.
A workaround could be to use

```
gcloud compute copy-files --dry-run ...
```

take the output and add

```
-P portnumber
```

flag to the raw scp command, but it is not a comfortable solution (especially when compared to the deprecated **gcutil push** which supports specifying custom port by using --ssh_port flag as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/reference/other#push)).

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible if you use `gcloud beta compute scp` command instead. This one has a `--port` flag that you can specify, or even `--scp-flag` for passing in any arbitrary flag that standalone `scp` supports (in the same way that `gcloud compute ssh` accepts standard `ssh` flags via `--ssh-flag` parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to do this. You can use `gcloud compute config-ssh` and then you can use scp directly or use your own workaround.